# Убрать элемент из страницы

Tags: android, javascript, html

Пишу приложение для андроида, там есть собственный местный браузер, он заходит на страницу, и из этой страницы нужно убрать id header.
Строка

```
 view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsById('header').style.display = 'none'; ");
```

почему-то не работает, но если сделать так

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementsByClassName('header'); document.write(x); ");
```

то он выведет `[objectHTMLCollection`].
При этом если сделать так

```
"javascript:var x = document.getElementsByClassName('header');  x.style.display = 'none';"
```

то тоже ничего не происходит.
Вопрос: как мне всё же скрыть этот элемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"javascript:var x = document.getElementsByClassName('header');  x.style.display = 'none';"
```

надо переделать как то так:

```
"javascript:var x = document.getElementsByClassName('header'); for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
 x[i].style.display = 'none';}"
```

Comment: нет, тоже почему то не работает, [objectHTMLCollection] если он выдаёт так, то это получается массив?

Comment: Ну, вообще да, это набор нод, а значит там существует их список. Надо пройти по списку, вот смотрите: http://jsfiddle.net/52opq6k2/

Comment: @binliz Спасибо за помощь, но работает такой способ


                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('header').style.display ='none';})()");

                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.setVisible()");

Comment: Тоже как вариант, действительно получается, вы так передаете всего одну функцию.